# Скрипт ходьбы и бега Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

С ходьбой у персонажа всё отлично, попытался сделать аналогично бег, только увеличть его скорость вдвое, то есть walkSpeed * 2, только когда зажата клавиша Shift и A или D, делал не через стринг, а через бул. Почему с ходьбой все работает отлично, а с бегом такие траблы?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    Animator anim;
    [SerializeField] private float walkSpeed;

    private string buttonPressed;
    private bool playerRuns;

    public const string RIGHT = "right";
    public const string LEFT = "left";

    private void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    { 
        //WALK
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            buttonPressed = RIGHT;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            buttonPressed = LEFT;
        }
        else
        {
            buttonPressed = null;
        }

        //RUN
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                playerRuns = true;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                playerRuns = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            playerRuns = false;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (playerRuns == true)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(walkSpeed * 2.0f * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }

        //Walk
        if (buttonPressed == RIGHT)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
        }
        else if (buttonPressed == LEFT)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
        }
        else
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
            anim.SetBool("Walk", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`GetKey` - зажата ли клавиша

`GetKeyDown` - событие нажатия

Условия в `FixedUpdate` сломанные, `if (playerRuns) else` не имеет значения, поскольку что бы оно не сделало `if (buttonPressed == RIGHT) else if (buttonPressed == LEFT) else` всё равно изменят результат.

Ещё при одновременном A и D игнорируется A, что плохо.

```
enum kSide { None, Left, Right }
kSide MoveSide;
bool IsRunning;

private void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        MoveSide = kSide.Right;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        MoveSide = kSide.Left;
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
        MoveSide = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) ? kSide.Left : kSide.None;
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
        MoveSide = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) ? kSide.Rigt : kSide.None;
    IsRunning = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
}

private void FixedUpdate () {
    float Speed = 0;
    if (MoveSide != kSide.None)
        Speed = MoveSide == kSide.Right ? walkSpeed : -walkSpeed;
    if (IsRunning)
        Speed *= 2f;
    rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(Speed*Time.deltaTime, 0);
    anim.SetBool("Walk", MoveSide != kSide.None);
}
```

Твои простые `if (bool) X = A else X = B` легко заменяются конструкцией `X = bool ? A : B`.

Comment: Тернаный оператор можно использовать только при присвоении значения, с `return` не выйдет.

Comment: Хотел написать как-то понятнее, но вышла глупость. =)

Comment: @Yaroslav, спасибо большое, буду дальше учить и разбираться)

Comment: @MaximKapko если ответ вам помог - отблагодарите автора: поставьте +1 и примите ответ, как правильный.